# Dismiss a viewController after using a push method

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I use this function to push a new viewController:

```
func goToPasscodeSetupVC() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PassCode", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "passcodeSetupVC") as! PasscodeSetupVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

But, when I am on the new viewController, I want to dismiss the previous one so that I could't reach it with a swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to disable swipe back gesture.

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `setViewControllers` instead of `pushViewController`

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PassCode", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "passcodeSetupVC") as! PasscodeSetupVC
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: true)
```